# Load data from an excelsheet into a SQL database

Tags: sql

I have an excelsheet with 5 columns of data. I have a corresponding table in the SQL database with some data. I want to update that existing table with new data from my excelsheet.

How can I export/load data from that excelsheet into the SQL database?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? Is this one time load?

Comment: You'll probably want to state which database software you are talking about. Oracle, MySQL, MSSQL etc

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle, try the **SQL Loader** utility (if you have Oracle, you already have that installed, you don't need to install that separately); in case you're using Sybase, check out the **BCP** command. In case your database is none of these, Google and find out if there exists something on similar lines ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of tools you can use.  You can also use a spread sheet to generate an sql statement.  For my example you have one column of numbers.

Insert a column before those numbers add the following line and copy it down the whole sheet

```
  Insert into tablename (id) values (
```

Then after the in the column after put

```
  )
```

Copy that down the whole sheet

It will now look like this (there is a typo in the image it should be `values` not `value`:

[image]

Now select your whole sheet, copy to clipboard and paste to a text editor, bingo you have SQL statements.

Of course this is a simple one column example.  If you have more values you will need to add columns for the `,` and if you have strings you will need to add in the `'` on both sides (you might also have to remove whitespace depending on the spreadsheet and the editor).